# Cron Job status check by code

Tags: php, server, cron

We have multiple crons in over system and some of crons depend upon parent cron but sometime parent cron is stop than all the child cron not working properly. There are any possibility if cron job is stop working than server send a mail to user email or show any other alert.

Comment: Post some code and errors you might run into. Also, how is this php related?

Comment: What is your cron code. because cron sends an email to user. If it doesn't set to be blackhole dev

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output of `crontab -l` to see if a particular crontab entry is present or not. As for if cron is running or not, you can parse the output of a `ps -eaf` command to see if crond is running or not.

You can use the `system()` function in PHP to call command line tools or `exec()`.

EG:

```
exec("PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin; service crond status", $output, $return);
print $return . "n";
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could run a monitor-cron on a different server to monitor health of your other crons. There are several ways for monitoring:

```
1) Your parent cron could set a flag in database to indicate its running state.
2) Your monitor cron could read output of "ps -eaf" command to check if parent cron is running or not
```

Your monitor-cron first should check if the server where parent cron is running is available or not.

Regards,